# Removing outliers using IQR from multiple groups within the same column

Tags: r

| Group | Exam #1 Score |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 33 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 1 | 66 |
| 2 | 99 |
| 1 | 93 |
| 1 | 26 |
| 3 | 37 |
| 3 | 88 |
| 3 | 83 |
| 1 | 89 |

I’m looking to compute the IQR outliers from exam #1 score from each Group individually. So it would like this:

Find IQR outliers of exam #1 score from group 1 individually

Find IQR outliers of exam #1 score from group 2 individually

Find IQR outliers of exam #1 score from group 3 individually

Remove all of those outliers from the entire exam score #1 column

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Filtering our the outliers? Or just finding the lower and upper IQR values per group? Please share an example of your data! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, I want to filter out the lower and upper outliers where lower outliers = Q1 - (1.5 x IQR) and upper outlier = Q3 + (1.5 x IQR)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is stored in an object `df` and depending how your exam score column is named, you can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  group_by(Group) |>
  mutate(q1 = quantile(exam_score, 0.25),
         q3 = quantile(exam_score, 0.75),
         iqr = q3 - q1) |>
  filter(exam_score > q1 - 1.5 * iqr & exam_score < q3 + 1.5 * iqr) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-q1, -q3, -iqr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply base function `boxplot.stats` to determine which points are outliers with `ave`.

```r
df1<-'Group     "Exam #1 Score"
2   33
2   23
1   66
2   99
1   93
1   26
3   37
3   88
3   83
1   89'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(df1), header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

i <- ave(df1$`Exam #1 Score`, df1$Group, FUN = \(x) !x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out)
df1[as.logical(i),]
#>    Group Exam #1 Score
#> 1      2            33
#> 2      2            23
#> 3      1            66
#> 4      2            99
#> 5      1            93
#> 6      1            26
#> 7      3            37
#> 8      3            88
#> 9      3            83
#> 10     1            89
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>